# ExecutorService seems to be running thread on The UI?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, executorservice

Iam attempting to use ExecutorService to run some code to connect my client to a server. Obviously Iam trying to get this to run on a seperate thread to the UI Thread, But my UI freezes when the code is executing.Which is not what I was excpecting. I thought ExecutorService would run on a seperate thread? below is my code

```
@Override
public void registerDevice() {


    ExecutorService exservice = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Future<Boolean> future = exservice.submit(new Callable() {

        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {

        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(20000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            reghandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    regpresenter.updateUIProgress();
                }
            });


            return true;
        }
    });

    exservice.shutdown();
    try {
        Boolean done = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        warningstr = "Server call timed out!";
    }
   exservice.shutDownNow();

}
```

If anyone can tell my why this doesnt run seperate to the UI thread I would be grateful. Maybe there is something Iam missing after reading all the docs on executor service. also I have another solution that seems to work but it creates a circular dependency with a timertask within my run method of another thread. The timertask interrupts the thread after timeout, if The thread is alive. so I dont really want to use that solution. Also iam just testing the timeout works at present. Ive left out some of the code in the method as its not really relevant to my issue. Thanks again

Comment: `Boolean done = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` is a blocking call meaning you will be blocked until 10 secs or your callable is done.

Comment: so the calling thread is blocked when i call future.get()???

Comment: thanks i didnt realise that. damn!

Comment: Is the best solution to this issue to just run future.get() in a seperate thread?

Comment: You should turn your comment into an answer @SMA.

Comment: As long as no time-maschine is invented, you will have to wait (block the Thread), if you want to read a value which is calculated in the future. (That is why, the class is called Future.

Comment: If not iam going to answer it. is that legal. lol

Comment: i understand that. thats why iam showing a progressdialog. as long as its not on the UI thread alls good homie!

Comment: Why are you creating an `ExecutorService`, and then shutting it down after it performs just one task?  That seems to be contrary to the entire purpose of `ExecutorService`.

Comment: not sure how else to create a timeout for a long running task to be honest

Answer (score 0):

Below code means to wait to task result (maximum with 10 seconds timeout)

```
Boolean done = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

if you don't want to wait till task is completed, don't call get().